# How to Authenticate on Linux

Tags: linux, authentication

I was running the following command on Linux as an underprivileged user:

```bash
systemd-run --on-calendar='* *-6-3 12:00:00' /bin/echo "Buy Chocolate!"
```

then it asked me for my credentials:

```bash
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or other units.
Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu)
Password: 
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Running timer as unit: run-u179.timer
Will run service as unit: run-u179.service
```

My question is how can I do the same thing in my own scripts?
What module produces those outputs between `====` lines?